# Rails deployed on heroku: Chart Kick is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, chartkick

I'm trying to get chartkick to work on heroku. It works locally but not when deployed. This is the error i'm getting.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined
>       at :2:3
>       at r.assignNewBody (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at r.replaceBody (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570
>       at r.e.renderView (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at r.render (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at Function.e.render (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at t.renderSnapshot (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at t.render (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)
>       at e.render (application-bb9e8f7bfe204d5bf8881251f3d2f2ccdd2040ddb8742362c0b73c5f15b29418.js:11570)

This is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require_tree
```

This is the gem

```
gem "chartkick"
```

This is the page when the charts should display

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-lead h3 text-center report-title">Overview of aggreagted patient data</div>
    <div class="row chart-labels text-muted">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <label class="ml-1" for="patients-illness">A summary of your patients illness's</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <label for="patients-hospital">Patients Location</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row charts">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="patients-illness">
            <%= pie_chart  current_user.patients.group(:ailment).count %>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6" id="patients-hospital">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row chart-labels text-muted">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <label for="patients-status">Patients current status</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="patients-status">
            <%= bar_chart current_user.patients.group(:status).count, colors: ["#8506A9"] %>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what I get on screen

[image]

The charts should appear where 'loading' is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone! I'm desperate

Comment: Did you precompile your assets before deploying to heroku?  Run: bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production         
Then run: git commit -m "Precomped assets for production"  then push to heroku.

Comment: I'll try that now. I didn't precompile my assets

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. This is weird, it's working locally with no issue